# monorepo productivity: Watch multiple packages

Tags: javascript, typescript, windows, rollup, lerna

I am struggeling with multi-package development in javascript. Everything is working as expected when building, thanks to `lerna`, but development feels slow, because I have to restart watchers everytime an upstream package changed.

I have a monorepo which contains a few typescript libraries (`a`,`b`,`c`), a web app (`web`).  All of these are npm separate, standalone packages (`package.json`), with separate build and watch goals. The monorepo is currently set up with `yarn, lerna, rollup (libs) & webpack (app), windows`.

They depend on each other like this:

```
a 
  \
b --> c ---> web
```

My workflow is as follows:

- I start `a`, `c` and `web` in "watch" mode, so they pick up source code changes and rebuild.
- I change sources in `a`. A rebuild for `a` is triggered and succeeds.
- Neither `c` nor `web` rebuild, so I stop these
- I rebuild `c` "manually"
- I start `web` in dev mode again.

The thing is, that watch mode *feels* faster than the triggering a full build manually, but maybe thats because of caching of `node_modules`?

So my question is: Whats the reason that `c` does not pick up the changes of `a` although its in watch mode? (And what do I have to change to make it work ;))